# "Balanced Paragraphs" in a Two-Column Flexbox Layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I have some code that looks like this

```
<div class="passage-container">
    <p>Paragraph 1...</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2...</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3...</p>
    <p>Paragraph 4...</p>
    <p>Paragraph 5...</p>
    <p>Paragraph 6...</p>
</div>
```

If all of the paragraph text was the same length, I could column break it after Paragraph 3 and have Paragraph 4 start the new column. But the kicker is some paragraphs that will be longer/shorter than others, so it's possible, for example, I'd want Paragraphs 1 and 2 to be in the first column, then Paragraphs 3-6 in the second.

Is there a way using CSS only to achieve this feature where flexbox will adjust which paragraphs are shown in one column vs. another based on how much content is within the paragraph, so the columns will be balanced?

Thanks

Comment: Consider posting a complete example, with paragraph text and CSS, so we can test it out.

Comment: There is no such feature in CSS. The paragraphs will be displayed as they are positioned in the DOM. But you can balance the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try css columns

```
.passage-container {
    columns: 2;
}
```

They work well but can sometimes be frustrating but the break-side/before/after rules can help you handle the formatting. See for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Answer (score 1):

The paragraphs will be displayed as they are positioned in the DOM. But you can balance the text.

```css
.passage-container {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 50px;
}
.passage-container p {
  text-align: justify;
}
.passage-container p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="passage-container">
  <p>1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, nesciunt.</p>
  <p>2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad nam beatae adipisci facere ipsum. Tempora corporis nostrum qui distinctio impedit!</p>
  <p>3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit tempora maxime delectus fuga sapiente commodi, nihil fugit neque distinctio consequuntur modi eligendi sequi, nemo quasi soluta voluptas cupiditate, quas beatae!</p>
  <p>4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, nesciunt.</p>
  <p>5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad nam beatae adipisci facere ipsum. Tempora corporis nostrum qui distinctio impedit!</p>
  <p>6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad nam beatae adipisci facere ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit tempora maxime delectus fuga sapiente commodi, nihil fugit neque distinctio consequuntur modi
    eligendi sequi, nemo quasi soluta voluptas cupiditate, quas beatae!</p>
</div>
</div>
```